# Showing a collection association in an ASP.NET class diagram - "System.Collections.Generic.List<Type> cannot be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, class-diagram

I am trying to show a collection association on a class diagram file in an ASP.NET project.

For now, the diagram looks like the following:
[image: Full diagram]

I would like to show the relation between Metrics (which is a List) and the Metric table, as well as the Statistics one.

Here is the DBConnection code:

```
public class DBConnection
{       
    public SQLiteConnection Database { get; set; }
    public List<Metric> Metrics { get; set; }
    public List<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }

    /* Rest of the class */
}
```

And the metric, it is in the same namespace as the DBConnection:

```
public class Metric
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string MetricDate { get; set; }
    public DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string MetricValue { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

But when I click "Show as collection association" :

[image: Button clicked]

I get the following error :

[image: Error display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem solved itself by restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the project (ctrl + alt + F7).

The `List` link can now be seen on the diagram :

[image]